# Bevel edges on rectangle not working as expected

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to bevel edges on a rectangular shape so that it matches the shape of the object behind it(more roundish), but when i do so I end up with a spape shat is proportional to the sides of the rectangle. I tried all the settings on the bevel menu without any luck, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Apply the scale in object mode.

Comment: @FFeller if I apply the scale(1 i assume) my dimensions go back to cube

Comment: @FFeller, oh, I see what you saying. I was trying to change scaling on object properties rather than actyally scale it

Comment: @lemon Yes it does!